# App fails to compile and run in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have made a basic application with one Splash Screen Activity and one Main Screen Activity(with Navigation Drawer). When I click "Run" Button, one error is shown in the Messages Box.

Android Studio Version: 2.2.3.

The code in build.gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The error goes as this:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Users\vijtech\AndroidStudioProjects\Deadline\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\design\25.3.1\jars\classes.jar'.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add code as text not as link to an image

Comment: I re-installed Android 2.2.3 again and now, that works for me. It appears that I was facing some issues regarding SDK Tools. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have permission to the file. Double check if you can read or write to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

**File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment ->Build tools -> gradle -> check Use Default gradle wrapper(recommended)** radiobutton.

You can try **File > Invalidate Caches/Restart** too

Comment: I tried doing both the things you mentioned. But the error have now changed.


**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Users\vijtech\AndroidStudioProjects\Deadline\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\recyclerview-v7\25.3.1\jars\classes.jar'.**

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your dependencies in your `build.gradle (app)`.

Go to **File -> Project Structure -> Messages -> Check for Updates**

Then it will show you, and you just need to upgrade it in your file.